# MS Botframework using .NetCore 2 not authenticating using Emulator

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using the **Bot Application Core 2.0 (.Net Framework)** Project template to generate Chat Bot. Have added Nuget packages **Microsoft.Bot.Connector (3.11.1)**, **Microsoft.Bot.Builder (3.11.0)** and **System.IdentityModel.TokenJwt(4.0.4.403061554)**.

According to [this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-authentication-problems)

1. I've confirmed that the Chatbot works using the emulator deployed on localhost without App ID and password credentials.
2. I have confirmed that Bot is registered and HTTP request to the Microsoft login service provides an access token.

As soon as I try to connect with the emulator with the security credentials the Bot does not work, when I type text it responds: **POST connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51002**

I've confirmed the App ID and Password are correct in the app.config file.

For some reason the authentication is not working (not getting Jwt Token), I've searched and found the following links that may be related to the issue but need more direction to resolve:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2289
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1473 https://github.com/DamianReeves/EchoBotForCore
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2237

It seems I'll need to write the authentication code myself to provide the credentials for the Bot to work with them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Show us the relevant code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time .NET core 2.0 is not supported.  We are currently working on a release to support .NET core 2.0 it is in testing right now.  I will update this post when it is with samples and any documentation resources available.